# Using Range.Find in For Loop - Not Returning a Range Excel VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, find, range

I am looping through a certain range of data that is a list of strings, and trying to find that string in another range in another workbook. I then want to copy the adjacent data from the first range to the correct row in the second range.

I am getting "Nothing" returned as a range from range.find. I am not sure I am using it properly but I cannot, after a couple hours of debugging, figure out why.

I have tried debugging and running my loop one at a time but everything comes back as "Nothing". I have checked all spelling in both ranges and both ranges contain the arguments.

```
For i = 1 To ptDataLastRow - ptDataFirstRow - 1
        ptString = Workbooks(JDEWkbk).Worksheets(1).Cells(ptDataFirstRow + i, PTColNo).Value2
        Workbooks(scrapWkbk).Worksheets(runMonth).Activate
        Set defectRow = Workbooks(scrapWkbk).Worksheets(runMonth).Range("A1, A" & scrapLastRow).Find(what:=ptString)
Next
```

Comment: My error seems to be in the `Set defectRow =` line. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("A1, A" & scrapLastRow)
```

...is just two cells.

Should be

```
Range("A1:A" & scrapLastRow)
```

Comment: Oh my word, I couldn't see that for over an hour. Thank you. :)

Comment: Is there any way to store the data as a (row, col)?

Comment: Store what data?

Comment: Sorry, I meant store the range. But I realized I could use `range.row` and `range.column`

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way to define the range with 2 cells - left upper and bottom right:

```
With Workbooks(scrapWkbk).Worksheets(runMonth)
    Set defectRow = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(scrapLastRow, "A")).Find(what:=ptString)
End With
```

Or you may use the `Range("A1:A" & scrapLastRow)`, but the previous one gives a bit more flexibility.